# How can I print an array A[n][m]; using main() that was scanf() in a subprogram?

Tags: c, matrix, scanf

In the below code I am trying to `scanf()` a matrix in a subprogram, and then I want to `printf()` it in the `main()` section. How can I achieve this? My main goal is to fully understand how I can pass matrices from a subprogram into the `main()` program. Thank you!

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define R 2
#define C 3

float save_the_matrix(int N, int M, float (*B)[M]);

int main(void)
{
  int n=2,m=3;
  int i,j;
  float A[n][m],C[n][m];

  puts("Enter the values of the matrix:");
  save_the_matrix( n, m, c);

  for(i=0;i<n;i++)
  {
    for(j=0;j<m;j++)
      printf("%6.2f",C[i][j]);
    printf("\n");
  }

  return 0;
}


float save_the_matrix(int N, int M, float (*B)[M])

{
  for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    for(j=0;j<M;j++)
    {
      printf("A[%d][%d]=",i,j);
      (*B)[M]=scanf("%f",&A[i][j]);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think there are just too many errors in your code to offer a sensible answer! For example, your `#define C 3` line will cause a **huge** conflict with the later declaration of `C` as an array variable. And you use a variable `A` in `save_the_matrix` but where is that declared?

Comment: Hi @AdrianMole, thanks a lot for your answer. Just trying to correct my code, but not really getting a good result. Any chance you could fix the things that are not correct? It would really help me in speeding up my learning of this part of C. Just started a few days ago. Thanks very much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you know exactly the size of array, you should use the declaration:

```
float save_the_matrix(int N, int M, float B[N][M]);
```

So, the implementation of this function:

```
float save_the_matrix(int N, int M, float B[N][M])
{
  int i,j;
  for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    for(j=0;j<M;j++)
    {
      printf("B[%d][%d]=",i,j);
      scanf("%f",&B[i][j]);
    }
}
```

You do not need to define `R` and `C` because, it can make the conflict in your code.

```
save_the_matrix( n, m, c);
```

Should use `C` instead of `c`

You should use `-Wall -Wextra` when you compile to show the warning in your code. For example the declaration of matrix `A`: `float A[n][m]` that is declared but not used.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Hitokiri!!!! Again helping in my quest to getting some knowledge in C! :-) I am getting these errors right now: https://screencast.com/t/pu4jdjdFs8rh Any chance you could point me in the right direction to finish this up? Thank you very very much!!

Comment: Use `C` instead of `c` as my answer. And, may be in the MacOS, you should not  `int i` and `int j` in for loop. You can declare `int i, j` out of for loop. I updated this declaration in my answer, hope it can help you.

Comment: Getting closer @Hitokiri!! :-) Not really sure how to declare `C` properly to get this completed: https://screencast.com/t/f2nTswYfs Thank you!!

Comment: please, using UPPERCASE `C` not LOWERCASE `c` at line 12

Comment: Ah right @Hitokiri. This final code works perfect now: https://screencast.com/t/NHv6iY2pvO Thanks very much for all your help. This will certainly help me in understanding how to work with multidimensional arrays. Thanks again for all your help!!!